# Residual tuples enumeration

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am very interested in the answer to one question. I would be grateful for your help!

All pairs of the residues $(x \bmod a, x \bmod b),\; x \in \mathbb{N}, a,b \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ can be listed using the expression:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{a}{(a,b)}}\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{b}{(a,b)}}\sum_{k=1}^{(a,b)}
\left( a-f(i,k),\; b-f(j,k)\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x,y) = (x-1)(a,b) + y
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**Question:** Is there generally representation for tuples
$(x \bmod a_1, \ldots, x \bmod a_n)$ exists?

In particular is the following expression possible:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i_1=1}^{\frac{a(a,b,c)}{(a,b)(a,c)}}
\sum_{i_2=1}^{\frac{b(a,b,c)}{(a,b)(b,c)}}
\sum_{i_3=1}^{\frac{c(a,b,c)}{(a,c)(b,c)}}
\sum_{j_1=1}^{\frac{(a,b)}{(a,b,c)}}
\sum_{j_2=1}^{\frac{(a,c)}{(a,b,c)}}
\sum_{j_3=1}^{\frac{(b,c)}{(a,b,c)}}
\sum_{k=1}^{(a,b,c)}F
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F := (a-f(i_1,j_1,j_2,k),\; b-f(i_2,j_1,j_3, k),\; c-f(i_3,j_2,j_3, k))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

for triplets $(x \bmod a, x \bmod b, x \bmod c),\; x \in \mathbb{N},\; a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$? If yes, what the function $f$ looks like?